# how to convert a column in percentage which contains both cgpa and percentage values

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, exploratory-data-analysis

I have student data which contains column 10_grade which consists both percentage and cgpa values mix.. I need to convert 10_grade column into percentage. A python code will be helpful

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `print(df.head().to_string())` and the expected outcome, please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its been sorted.. now i want to plot these 3 categorical variables together 1) Graduation_Location (Mumbai region,south region,north region,others)
2) Course_Country (us and canada, asian countries, European countries, others)
3) status (hold reject , others)

I was able to plot two wiith the help of pd.crosstab

pd.crosstab(df.Grad_Location,df.Course_Country)

Comment: Looks like you have solved your own issue and asked a new one. You should delete this question (or provide the solution) and ask a new question.